# javascript form / comparing randomly generated number to user input

Tags: javascript, forms

I'm trying to compare a randomly generated number to a number input by the user (via a form in HTML). The JavaScript function executes instantly when the page is loaded, rather than waiting for the user to enter a number in the form. Also the form input does not seem to be doing anything.

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hot Or Cold</title>
<script type ="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="gameBox">
<p>Enter a number between 1 and 100</p>
<input type="text" name="userinput" id="userinput" maxlength="3" autocomplete="off"/>
<input type ="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="button"/>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

and my JavaScript code:

```
var computer = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);

var user = document.getElementById("#userinput");

function game(user, computer){
    if (user == computer) {
        alert("You picked the correct number!");
    }
    else if (user > computer) {
        alert("Too high.");
    }
    else if (user < computer) {
        alert("Too low.");
    }
}

game();
```

Comment: You can't compare an HTML element to a number.  You want to parse the element's value into a number.  You also want to handle a click event.

Comment: user = document.getElementById("userinput").value  , NO # in getElementById, # is used in jquery

Answer (score 0):

It is not working how you expect because your submit button doesn't do anything, and you are in fact calling your function when the page loads.
Remove the last line of our JavaScript, the call to

```
game();
```

Change your submit button to this

```
<input type=button onclick=game(); class=submit value=Submit>
```

Remove the closing

```
</form>
```

tag since you have no opening form, but you dont need one.

Also to get the input number

```
var user = parseFloat(document.getElementById("userinput").value);
```

Since js does not use hash before ids like jquery, and form values are all strings until they are parsed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an event handler so that your function is called when the form is submitted, like so:

```
document.getElementById('myform').addEventListener('submit', function(e){
    var user = document.getElementById("userinput").value;

    game(user, computer);

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I fixed your code in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d9ETT/).

Comment: thanks for the input. when i tried using this code, i'm getting an uncaught type error: cannot call method "addEventListener" of null. i guess it's referring to the form?

Comment: i got rid of getElementbyId("myform")  (and kept the rest of the code the same) and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

i'm writing the entire code hope you get it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>
<h1> Game </h1>
<input type="number" id="id1">
<button type="button"
onclick=" game()">
Click me.</button>

<script>
var computer = Math.round(Math.random()*100);
console.log(computer);
var user=document.getElementById('id1').value;
function game(){
if(user == computer)
{
alert("yay! Good Work");
}
else{
alert("Sorry Not Matched");
}
}
</script>
</body>
</head>
</html>
```